# SERVICE FOR NOTIFICATIONS

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

Can anyone tell me how to do a service that will generate a notification every day at a certain time (for example at noon)?
Or rather, do I need a service to do this?
Naturally I am talking about Android programming

Comment: Use the new android work-manager to set up a job that will be run at a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, You can implement with options:

- AlarmManager
- Schedule job
- Server schedule job
- Or something other options,...